# bitcoins, how can someone receive much less than have spent?

Tags: bitcoin

Here is blockchain link:

https://blockchain.info/address/14f4WdcxkRhP2N5JbCWe3q7QcNtDiX82ba?filter=1

Here you can clearly see that that total received bitcoin was about, but he spent more than 200 i guess...

Can someone explain how is that even possible?

Comment: Total received BitCoin was about ...?

Comment: what? do you mean?

Comment: Isn't that sentence is incomplete. Anyway I can see he received 2.18494088 BTC, and final balance is 0.023108 BTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever who made these transactions had other sources of funds than just the account you queried. Thus he was able to form transactions that delivered more funds than that one account received.

If you total amount delivered by all of the transactions that drew from that account, they do total more than 200 Bitcoins. But those transactions drew from many accounts, not just this one.

For example, if you look closely at [transaction ce99101a40bcf2bceab57ac43ff881260a6961c546b9d52e0737ed6acd39a43a](https://blockchain.info/tx/ce99101a40bcf2bceab57ac43ff881260a6961c546b9d52e0737ed6acd39a43a?show_adv=true) you can see that while the transaction delivered over 25 Bitcoins, it had numerous input accounts. Only 0.1528 Bitcoins came from 14f4WdcxkRhP2N5JbCWe3q7QcNtDiX82ba.

Note that this is perfectly ordinary. Some wallets behave this way automatically, constantly generating additional accounts to hold funds and managing those sources as a unit, forming transactions that draw from several of them and returning unspent funds to yet another new account.

Comment: So the transaction amount that I see is from all those different addresses... I understand now... Thank you very much.